# How get user contacts list from EWS

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm developing web application which is similar to address-book,
now I want to create a page with list of user contacts. I already have user email and show out_of_office badge using GetUserOOFSettrings API method.

Does the API for getting user's (favorite) contacts list exists?
E.g. to get MS Lync contacts which user have, or outlook contacts...

Does some better way for implementation of current feature exists?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj190895(v=exchg.150).aspx. Contacts are just items in the user's mailbox. You might also download [EWSEditor](http://ewseditor.codeplex.com) to poke around and see what's available.